# How to install yum in Wind river linux?

Tags: linux, yum, wind-river-workbench

I want to install a few packages on wind river which again have lots of dependent packages. If I install all the dependent packages "Manually" it would be so cumbersome  and tedious.

To solve this problem I tried installing yum from source code, but this not installed successfully.

Comment: That's not how it works. Wind River is based on Yocto, and has nothing to do with yum sources in its current version (read: since 2012)

Comment: Wind River Linux is for **embedded** devices, which means that taking the "Desktop Distro" approach of having binaries to install on the live system doesn't make any sense. If you want that, you're using the wrong flavour of Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and more description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it.  Good Luck!

Comment: This question should be migrated to SuperUser!!!